# pyvirtualdisplay: Change visibility

Tags: python, selenium, pyvirtualdisplay

I would like to toggle visibility on/off for a display created using `pyvirtualdisplay`, or alternatively minimize it and bring it back to screen using python.

Unfortunately, there appears to be no method for this, and changing `display.visible` after initialization of the display is without effect. Is there some way I can do this, perhaps using some alternative package?

Ultimatively, I want to hide and show a firefox browser controlled via `selenium`.

Comment: I don't think this can be done directly via pyvirtualdisplaoy or selenium. You can use a hacky workaround though, which sets the screen position to be outside the bounds of your current window. See this for more: [How to minimize the browser window which was launched via Selenium Webdriver?](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/15484/how-to-minimize-the-browser-window-which-was-launched-via-selenium-webdriver)